# What criteria use in order to select the best internal validation for clustering?

Tags: clustering, k-means

I am doing homework about how to evaluate a clustering algorithm both hierarchical and partitional.

For doing this I have a dataset that I can plot as you can see:

[image]

The clustering algorithms that I am using are K-Means, Gaussian mixture, and Agglomerative.

The problem is that I don't know which criteria use for selecting an internal validation for K-MEANS, for example, I read that silhouette is better for a convex cluster, but I am not able to see in the image if any of groups are or aren't convex.

I am read some papers like:

- http://datamining.rutgers.edu/publication/internalmeasures.pdf
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.05667.pdf

but the problem is that I am not found any criteria to select A or B method for internal evaluation with facts, they're only a test about all vs all.

Where can found or what is found the criteria for choosing one or the other method for evaluation criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *catch-all* metric that can be used for evaluation (internal or otherwise) of the clustering achieved. This is why machine learning is also art. There are no hard limits, many things depend on application, domain, and data themselves.

**TL;DR**

**The purpose of the homework is to familiarise yourself with the problem of clustering, but also with the fact that there is no definite best method nor evaluation metric as *panacea* for all cases.**

*As such, you can try various criteria (see below references) on your data and algorithm results and ponder on their effectiveness for your problem at hand.*

**[An Impossibility Theorem for Clustering](https://www.cs.cornell.edu/home/kleinber/nips15.pdf)**

> Although the study of clustering is centered around an intuitively
> compelling goal,it  has been very difficult to develop a  unified
> framework for reasoning about it at a technical level, and profoundly
> diverse approaches to clustering abound in the research community.
> Here we suggest a formal perspective on the difficulty in  finding
> such a unification, in the form of an impossibility theorem: for a set
> of three simple properties, we show that there is no clustering
> function satisfying all three. Relaxations of these properties expose
> some of the interesting (and unavoidable) trade-offs at work in
> well-studied clustering techniques such as single-linkage,
> sum-of-pairs, k-means, and k-median.

[Wikipedia has a nice summary of internal evaluation metrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis#Internal_evaluation):

> Therefore, the internal evaluation measures are best suited to get
> some insight into situations where one algorithm performs better than
> another, but this shall not imply that one algorithm produces more
> valid results than another. Validity as measured by such an index
> depends on the claim that this kind of structure exists in the data
> set. An algorithm designed for some kind of models has no chance if
> the data set contains a radically different set of models, or if the
> evaluation measures a radically different criterion. For example,
> k-means clustering can only find convex clusters, and many evaluation
> indexes assume convex clusters. On a data set with non-convex clusters
> neither the use of k-means, nor of an evaluation criterion that
> assumes convexity, is sound.
>
> More than a dozen of internal evaluation measures exist, usually based
> on the intuition that items in the same cluster should be more similar
> than items in different clusters. For example, the following methods
> can be used to assess the quality of clustering algorithms based on
> internal criterion:
>
> **Davies–Bouldin index**
>
> The Davies–Bouldin index can be calculated by the following formula:
>
> $$DB={\frac {1}{n}}\sum _{i=1}^{n}\max _{j\neq i}\left({\frac {\sigma _{i}+\sigma _{j}}{d(c_{i},c_{j})}}\right)$$
>
> where $n$ is the number of clusters, $c_{x}$ is the centroid of cluster $x$, $\sigma _{x}$ is the average distance of all elements in
> cluster $x$ to centroid $c_{x}$, and $d(c_{i},c_{j})$ is the distance
> between centroids $c_{i}$ and $c_{j}$. Since algorithms that produce
> clusters with low intra-cluster distances (high intra-cluster
> similarity) and high inter-cluster distances (low inter-cluster
> similarity) will have a low Davies–Bouldin index, the clustering
> algorithm that produces a collection of clusters with the smallest
> Davies–Bouldin index is considered the best algorithm based on this
> criterion.
>
> **Dunn index**
>
> The Dunn index aims to identify dense and well-separated clusters. It is defined as the ratio between the minimal inter-cluster distance
> to maximal intra-cluster distance. For each cluster partition, the
> Dunn index can be calculated by the following formula:
>
> $$D={\frac {\min _{1\leq i<j\leq n}d(i,j)}{\max _{1\leq k\leq n}d^{\prime }(k)}}\,,$$
>
> where $d(i,j)$ represents the distance between clusters $i$ and $j$, and $d'(k)$ measures the intra-cluster distance of cluster $k$.
> The inter-cluster distance $d(i,j)$ between two clusters may be any
> number of distance measures, such as the distance between the
> centroids of the clusters. Similarly, the intra-cluster distance
> $d'(k)$ may be measured in a variety ways, such as the maximal
> distance between any pair of elements in cluster $k$. Since internal
> criterion seek clusters with high intra-cluster similarity and low
> inter-cluster similarity, algorithms that produce clusters with high
> Dunn index are more desirable.
>
> **Silhouette coefficient**
>
> The silhouette coefficient contrasts the average distance to elements in the same cluster with the average distance to elements in
> other clusters. Objects with a high silhouette value are considered
> well clustered, objects with a low value may be outliers. This index
> works well with k-means clustering, and is also used to determine the
> optimal number of clusters.

Furthermore:

[An Evaluation of Criteria for Measuring the Quality of Clusters](https://www.ijcai.org/Proceedings/99-2/Papers/035.pdf)

> An important problem in clustering is how to decide what is the best
> set of clusters for a given data set, in terms of both the number of
> clusters and the member-ship of those clusters.  In this  paper we
> develop four criteria for  measuring  the quality  of different  sets
> of clusters. These criteria are designed so that different criteria
> prefer cluster  sets that generalise at different levels  of
> granularity.  We  evaluate  the  suitability  of  these  criteria  for
> non-hierarchical  clustering  of  the  results returned by a search
> engine. We also compare the  number of clusters  chosen by  these
> criteria with the  number of clusters  chosen by a  group of human
> subjects.  Our  results  demonstrate  that  our  criteria  match  the
> variability  exhibited  by  human  subjects,  indicating there is no
> single perfect criterion. Instead, it is  necessary to select the
> correct criterion to match a human subject's generalisation needs.

[Evaluation Metrics for Unsupervised Learning Algorithms](https://arxiv.org/abs/1905.05667)

> Determining the quality of the results obtained by clustering
> techniques is a key issue in unsupervised machine learning. Many
> authors have discussed the desirable features of good clustering
> algorithms. However, Jon Kleinberg established an impossibility
> theorem for clustering. As a consequence, a wealth of studies have
> proposed techniques to evaluate the quality of clustering results
> depending on the characteristics of the clustering problem and the
> algorithmic technique employed to cluster data.

[Understanding of Internal Clustering Validation Measures](http://datamining.rutgers.edu/publication/internalmeasures.pdf)

> Clustering validation has long been recognized as one of the vital
> issues essential to the success of clustering applications. In
> general, clustering validation can be categorized into two classes,
> external clustering validation and internal clustering validation. In
> this paper, we focus on internal clustering validation and present a
> detailed study of 11 widely used internal clustering validation
> measures for crisp clustering. From five conventional aspects of
> clustering, we investigate their validation properties. Experiment
> results show that `_` is the only internal validation measure
> which performs well in all five aspects, while other measures have
> certain limitations in different application scenarios.